# using int for float division c++

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm new with c++, and i was messing around with the stuff i have learned thus far. I was messing with arrays and i came up with the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

// initializes an array with user defined size
int array_size;
cout << "Enter the amount of number you wish to enter: ";
cin >> array_size;
int arr[array_size];

int i = 0;
int element = 0;
int sum = 0;
float average = 0;

// populates the array with user inputted elements
do
{
    cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> element;
    arr[i] = element;
    sum = sum + element;
    ++i;
}
while(i < array_size);

int MAX = arr[0];
for(int i = 1; i < array_size; ++i)
    if(arr[i] > MAX)
        MAX = arr[i];

int MIN = arr[0];
for(int i = 1; i < array_size; ++i)
    if(arr[i] < MIN)
        MIN = arr[i];

for(int i = 0; i < array_size - 1; ++i)
    average = (average + arr[i])/array_size.0;

cout << "The biggest number that was entered was: " << MAX << endl;
cout << "The smallest number that was entered was: " << MIN << endl;
cout << "The sum of the numbers entered is: " << sum << endl;
cout << "The average of the numbers entered is: " << average << endl;

return 0;
}
```

i get an error on line 40: `error: expected ';' before numeric constant`
i believe its because im trying to append a `.0` for float division to a variable name, any way i can use `array_size` to perform float division?

Answer (score 1):

You can not append ".0" to a variable name. To cast it to float, use casting syntax:

```
average = float(average + arr[i]) / float(array_size);
```

---

Be sure to cast early, so that you would not round the result as int:

```
average = float(average + arr[i] / array_size); // might not work as expected
```

More on type casting: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

As an aside, if you want to add a number to an average, you might want to use a different formula:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/957376

Comment: In this case, you don't need casts at all, as `average` is already a float. In any operation between a float and an int, the int is implicitly converted to float (actually both are converted to double).

Comment: i have implemented that formula you provided but im not getting the desired results. Neither with the formula in my code example. ive been fiddling with it for quite some time but cannot seem to make it work, any suggestoins?

Answer (score 0):

Just do the operation -- whenever you do arithmatic with `float` variables, the operands will automatcially be converted to `double` to do the operation.  So you just need:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array_size - 1; ++i)
    average = (average + arr[i])/array_size;
```

since `average` has the type `float`, it and `arr[i]` will be both be converted to double to do a (double precision) floating-point addition.  Then, since that result is `double`, `array_size` will also be converted to `double` and a floating point divide will be done.  Finally, that `double` result will be converted back to `float` and stored in `average`